# Is there a way to poll several addresses using Mule's HttpPollingConnector?

Tags: http, mule, polling, mule-studio

I am trying to poll several addresses (URL links) from a list that contains all these addresses using the http polling connector in Mule. Currently, I am only able to poll from one address but I would like to find a way to use this list to iterate the polling for each site. Is there anything built within Mule that provides such function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is composite source what you're looking for? It allows you to have more than one endpoint in the inbound.

e.g. from http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Bookstore+Example

```
<flow name="CatalogService">
    <composite-source>
        <!-- Public interface -->
        <inbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:8777/services/catalog" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="org.mule.example.bookstore.CatalogService" />
        </inbound-endpoint>

        <!-- Administration interface -->
        <inbound-endpoint address="servlet://catalog" exchange-pattern="request-response">
            <!-- Convert request parameters to Book object -->
            <custom-transformer class="org.mule.example.bookstore.transformers.HttpRequestToBook" />
            <response>
                <!-- Format response to be a nice HTML page -->
                <custom-transformer class="org.mule.example.bookstore.transformers.AddBookResponse" />
                <!-- Force text/html, otherwise it falls back to request 
                    props, which have form-encoded one -->
                <transformer ref="setHtmlContentType" />
            </response>
        </inbound-endpoint>
    </composite-source>
    ....
```

Edit:

The following is a simple foreach example:

```
<flow name="foreachFlow1" doc:name="foreachFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <foreach collection="#[groovy:['localhost:8082', 'localhost:8083']]" doc:name="For Each">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://#[payload]" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
<flow name="foreachFlow2" doc:name="foreachFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="in flow2" level="INFO"/>
</flow>
<flow name="foreachFlow3" doc:name="foreachFlow3">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="in flow3" level="INFO"/>
</flow>
```

Basically, the 'tricky' part is to figure out that the payload becomes the current item in the collection you're iterating over (the docs do a wonderful job at pointing that out... well at least if you're into fishing :P).

Comment: Not quite, I want to be able to put all the addresses within an array or list in the inbound. Is there a way to be able to do this in Mule?

Comment: I don't think you can. Mule is build on Spring... the address attribute in the inbound maps to a Java property set using a setter method. If the 'address' property is a String, you cannot set a List or Array.

Comment: I see. Then would there be an alternative way such as putting a list or array somewhere else and iteratively using the same inbound endpoint? I'm trying to do this because it would be more optimal to do what I mentioned earlier than to have different inbound endpoints doing the same poll request but with different http addresses.

Comment: Ok.. I'm reading this again and it seems I misunderstood what you're trying to do. If you're polling you don't need an inbound, you want an outbound http message processor. No need for composite source then... this is simply a matter of using Mule's foreach to iterate through your list of addresses and poll (http:outbound) on each.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me some sort of direction as to how I would be able to approach this? Like how I would be able to iteratively go through my list and poll? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Emm, added an edit to my original answer with a very simple example. Hopefully, that should get you going.

Comment: Hi justin, I was wondering whether you can explain to me what the `groovy` is used for for the array of `localhosts`

Comment: Hi Emm, Groovy is only being used to pass in a collection. You said you already had a list of addresses. In that case you can specify where the collection is instead of creating one with Groovy (i.e. specify whether it's in the payload or some session variable or something).