# Iterating an array using Mule's foreach scope

Tags: foreach, mule

I would like to iterate through an array and use the value taken from the array to put it within an http inbound endpoint. How would I be able to iterate through this array and take the value from the array to place it as a variable within the http inbound endpoint?

The code that I used to try was:

```
<flow name="foreachFlow1" doc:name="foreachFlow1">
    <poll frequency="2000">
    <foreach collection="#[groovy:['localhost:8082', 'localhost:8083']]"
        doc:name="For Each">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            address="http://#[payload]" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" />
    </foreach>
    </poll>
</flow>
```

and I get the error

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'poll'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve: listen to a bunch of different ports/paths? I'll review my answer based on your clarifications.

Comment: I'm trying to poll several addresses using <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://www.google.com" connector-ref="PollingHttpConnector" doc:name="HTTP"/> with the address field containing a variable in order to poll through different addresses. Therefore I was thinking of using an array to iterate through the list of addresses to poll. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Emm, basically, each item in the iteration gets bound to the payload so you would use #[payload] to access it. There is an example in your prev question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970495/is-there-a-way-to-poll-several-addresses-using-mules-httppollingconnector/18981395#18981395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inbound endpoints are message sources and can not be parametrized the way you're describing.

To achieve your goal, trying a `<poll>` message source to wrap a `foreach` that uses `http:outbound-endpoint` to perform `GET` (@method) `request-response` (@exchange-apttern) interactions.

The trick is to bring the results for the HTTP calls back through the `foreach`, which by default do not do it. The following illustrate a potential approach:

```
<flow name="foreachFlow1">
    <poll frequency="2000">
        <processor-chain>
            <set-variable variableName="httpResponses" value="#[[]]" />
            <foreach collection="#[groovy:['localhost:8082', 'localhost:8083']]">
                <http:outbound-endpoint
                    exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://#[payload]"
                    method="GET" />
                <expression-component>httpResponses.add(message.payloadAs(java.lang.String))
                </expression-component>
            </foreach>
        </processor-chain>
    </poll>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[httpResponses]" />
</flow>

<!-- Test server stubs -->

<flow name="server8082">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8082" />
    <set-payload value="This is 8082" />
</flow>

<flow name="server8083">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8083" />
    <set-payload value="This is 8083" />
</flow>
```

Comment: @davis I tried using the example from my previous question and used a <poll> message source to wrap the foreach but I get the error "Invalid content was found starting with element 'poll'". I edited my original question and put the code there

Comment: Remove the `<http:inbound-endpoint>`: you can only have one message source per flow and `poll` is a message source.

Comment: I forgot to show the commented out <http:inbound-endpoint> but even after removing it I still get the error.

Comment: You are and your config is perfectly valid on Mule 3.4.0 CE. I guess it's Studio not Mule that is reporting the `Invalid content was found starting with element 'poll'`? If that's the case, just ignore it, Studio doesn't fully grok the Mule XSD. The actual issue you're having is that `foreach` doesn't propagate the result of the message processors it contains back to the caller. I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: If I use the exact code from the example from my previous question but just comment out the `<http:inbound-endpoint>` and add `poll` I get the error `The content of element 'flow' is not complete.`. I don't understand why it would not be complete..

Comment: See my revised answer with complete, working samples.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it would be possible to replace the `localhosts` with URL links like `http://www.google.com/`?